# Flutter go_router redirect with object parameter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-go-router

Normally I can `go()` to a route, and specify `extra` to pass an object: `void go(String location, {Object? extra})`. How can I pass the `extra` parameter from the GoRoute's `redirect`?

```dart
      GoRoute(
        path: '/',
        redirect: (context, state) async {
          final theObject = tryToGetTheObject();
          if (theObject != null) {
            // context.go("/location", extra: theObject); -> throws error
            // return state.namedLocation("Location", extra: theObject); -> doesn't exist
            return state.namedLocation("Location"); // doesn't allow extra
          }
          return null;
        },
      ),
```

Alternatively, how can I load the object in the builder, since the (page)Builder may not be async (even though redirect is allowed to be):

```dart
      GoRoute(
        path: '/',
        redirect: (context, state) async {
          final theObject = tryToGetTheObject();
          if (theObject != null) {
            return state.namedLocation("Location");
          }
          return null;
        },
      ),
      GoRoute(
        name: 'Location',
        path: '/location',
        builder: (context, state) async { // async not allowed
          final theObject = state.extra ?? await tryToGetTheObject(); // async not allowed
          if (theObject == null) throw Exception("Invalid state");
          return LocationWidget(theObject);
        },
      ),
```

Comment: maybe you can send json data to redirect page with queryParameter as `Map<String,String>`.

Comment: @FeyizOktayAydır true, but unfortunately this workaround doesn't work for my situation, because my object can't be encoded as a Map<String,String>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's currently no official way to mutate the `GoRouterState` in redirects and I believe there's no good reason to have something like this implemented.

Your routing code should stay as simple as possible, at most parsing some path parameters (required) and query parameters (optional) to pass to the widget. Ideally these parameters are just IDs for objects that will later be *resolved* by the widget's controller/view model etc.

In your case, you work with an `extra` object that is optional.

As for query parameters, I believe the best practice is to pass `null` to the widget, leaving it the responsibility of *resolving* the default value.

Let's assume that `LocationWidget` is a `StatefulWidget`.

Since your function that loads the *object* is `async` you should store the result as a `Future<T>` and use a `FutureBuilder` to render the widget that depends on the *object*:

```dart
class LocationWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final LocationObject? object;

  const LocationWidget({
    super.key,
    this.object,
  });

  @override
  State<LocationWidget> createState() => _LocationWidgetState();
}

class _LocationWidgetState extends State<LocationWidget> {
  late Future<LocationObject?> _objectFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _objectFuture = widget.object != null ? Future.value(widget.object!) : _tryToGetObject();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<LocationObject?>(
      future: _objectFuture,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          final object = snapshot.data;
          return Text('Object: $object');
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          final error = snapshot.error;
          return Text('Error: $error');
        } else {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
      },
    );
  }

  Future<LocationObject?> _tryToGetObject() async {
    // TODO: implement
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple workaround, if you really need the `extra` property in the subroute. You can do this by creating an extra variable outside and then assigning it the value from the redirect whenever its needed. This way each time you go to a new route your variable gets overwritten. You can access the variable inside the subrouter to get the extras. Example:

```
class AppRouter {
  // Your extra variable
  Map<String, dynamic>? _extra;
  
  AppRouter({required this.auth});
  Auth auth;
  
  late GoRouter router = GoRouter(
    refreshListenable: auth,
    redirect: (context, state) {

      // considering the extra is a map
      _extra = state.extra as Map<String, dynamic>?;
      if (auth.isLoggedIn == false) {
        return Login.route;
      }

      if (state.location == "/second-page") {
        return SecondPage.route;
      }

      return Home.route;
    },
    routes: [
      GoRoute(
        path: Login.route,
        name: 'login',
        builder: (context, state) {
          return const Login();
        },
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: Home.route,
        name: 'Home_page',
        builder: (context, state) {

          // _extra is accessible here
          return Home(myKey: _extra);
        },
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: SecondPage.route,
        name: 'second_page',
        builder: (context, state) {
          return const SecondPage();
        },
      ),
    ],
    initialLocation: Home.route,
  );
}
```